Как изменить размер шрифта в gVim?
Вопрос как изменить размер шрифта в gVim.
Да, я новичок и да, я знаю что нужно добавить в строку vimrc что-то типа set guifont= и что-то там, но сколько не смотрел все по разному пишут, то с черточкой () то с двоеточием (:) а потом h(размер шрифта).
Напишите пожалуйста какой код нужно вставить в vimrc и в какое место. Напомню использую графический Vim (Не в терминале).
Устал просто постоянно при заходе в gVim писать в команду setguifont=:h16

а что вам мешает записать в ~/.gvimrc вот эту самую команду set guifont=:h16 (вы только пробел пропустили)?

У меня нету файла gvimrc, или мне нужно его создать?

Все проблему решил, спасибо

запустите ваш gvim и введите команду :e $MYGVIMRC. gvim подставит вместо переменной путь к актуальному ресурсному файлу. впишите ту самую желаемую вами команду set guifont=:h16 и сохраните файл. если его не существовало - он будет создан.

я просто скопировал файл _vimrc, переименовал его на _gvimrc, очистил и написал в этот файл команду set guifont=:h16. Теперь все работает.

В планах поставить плагин NERDTree, надеюсь у меня не займет много времени :)
